# UI hangs due to multiple loops:Need code optimisation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can somebody please help to optimize the code below.

The problem statement is : the user on the ui selects the various courses and add them to the a list of selected students. The courses can be applied to students in 2 ways :

1. selected courses are applied to selected students on ui
2. slected courses to be applied to all the students on the class.

The code below works as expected but the UI hangs becuase of multiple loops, can somebody please help optimise it.

Map  **coursesToApply** and Map  **coursesApplyToAll** : have couse Id and teacher(provided by user from the ui at run time).

```
@RequestMapping(value="/applycoursestostudents")
     public @ResponseBody List<ModificationStudentData> applycoursestostudentsToTrade(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,@RequestBody applyCoursesToStudents data){    
         ModificationStudentData ModificationStudentData = new ModificationStudentData();
         boolean saveAsDraft=data.isSaveAsDraft();
         String username=request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
         Map<Integer,String>  coursesToApply=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
         Map<Integer,String>  coursesApplyToAll=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
         List<ModificationStudentData> errorInRuleApplication=new ArrayList<ModificationStudentData>();
         int[] applyCoursesToStudents=data.getapplyCoursesToStudents();
         int[] allStudentRollNumbers=data.getallStudentRollNumbers();
         String caseRef=data.getCaseRef();
         int seq=data.getSeq();
         try{
             int StudentClass=service.getModificationStudentData(dataSource,caseRef,seq);
             coursesToApply=data.getcoursesToApply();
             coursesApplyToAll=data.getcoursesApplyToAll();
             try{
                 if(saveAsDraft){
                     removeExistingCourses(datSource,applyCoursesToStudents, username,StudentClass);
                 }
                 if(coursesToApply.size()>0 || coursesApplyToAll.size()>0){
                     for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : coursesApplyToAll.entrySet()) {
                         for(int rollNum:allStudentRollNumbers){
                             try{
                                 service.addCoursesToStudents(dataSource, entry.getKey(), rollNum, username,entry.getValue());
                             }catch(Exception e){
                                 e.printStackTrace();                               
                             }
                             if(!saveAsDraft){
                                 try{
                                     service.generateTermPlan(dataSource,StudentClass, rollNum, username);
                                 }catch(Exception e){
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                             }                           
                         }
                     }
                     for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : coursesToApply.entrySet()) {
                         for(int rollNum:applyCoursesToStudents){
                             try{
                                    service.addCoursesToStudents(dataSource, entry.getKey(), rollNum, username,entry.getValue());
                                }catch(Exception e){                                     
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                             if(!saveAsDraft){
                                 try{
                                     service.generateTermPlan(dataSource,StudentClass, rollNum, username);
                                 }catch(Exception e){
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }catch(NullPointerException e){
                 for(int rollNum:applyCoursesToStudents){
                     if(!saveAsDraft){
                         try{
                             service.generateTermPlan(dataSource,StudentClass, rollNum, username);
                         }catch(Exception ex){
                             ex.printStackTrace();
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             if(!saveAsDraft){
                 try{
                     service.getGeneratedReports(dataSource, StudentClass);
                 }
                 catch(Exception exp){
                     exp.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();

         }
         retrun null;
     }
```

Comment: why don't you make use of `@service` class?

Comment: By "multiple loops", you mean 2?

Comment: from `@service` class you can fetch multiple methods for every complexity and then add it to some data stricture and then retrieve it either in `@controller` or in your `view` . One more thing if you delegate your code in `@service`, chances of **code reuse** and **testing** will be great (esay)

Comment: could you provide a sample ?